# c++ cleaning the heap

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I am having serious issues in the heap because in the previous programs, I did not delete the pointers variables. How do I clean the memory space/heap now to run the current programs?

Comment: Do you mean you have a memory leak? If your computer ran out of memory, just restart it.

Comment: What sort of system are we talking about here? Regular Windows/Mac OS/Linux machine? Embedded system?

Comment: I am using secure shell to connect to a sun computer through mac osx command line.

Comment: You want to clean the momory of a process that is already dead? The OS will do that for you...

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense for any modern operating system. How are you determining that memory is not being released?

Answer (score 1):

Kill the offending processes, then the OS will clean up their memory for you.

Comment: not by the standard of course, but on a modern OS (e.g. sun as the OP stated) it will.

Comment: Agree - but an answer that 'works' on every OS - even ones to be created is better than a platform specific example. Relying on non standard features keeps maintenance programmer in business. VMS always set local vars to zero type values - not portable :-)

Comment: the problem is that there is no standard for OSs, there is no guarantee for as yet uncreated hardware that restarting will have any effect on the OS or memory, there is no guarantee that there will even be a restart feature. He is asking for a solution to a problem with no portable solution. Also generally you can't just restart a sun box --- there are often other people using it :D

Comment: I think restarting the box is good enough but you make a fair point for future hardware. I remember in the 90's being asked to write code to close DB tables neatly after the machine had lost power. That's what happens when you get requirements from customer service ;-) And if you've ever been a sysadmin there is a joy to rebooting boxes with little notice (BOFH)

Answer (score 0):

For every allocation you make on the heap with new/malloc or other such functions you must delete/free the resource that you have used when you are finished with it.

C++ makes available some easy ways to do this with constructors allocating resources and destructors free'ing the resource.

Then there are lots of clever ways with std::auto_ptr or even other smart pointers that can help you manage this.

Basically you allocated it - so it is your job to free it.

Comment: I do not remember those codes/ dynamic variables/pointers that I created because I deleted the code. Any other way to clean that?

Comment: yes, but usually the OS deletes everything after the process is dead, usually everything is sandboxed and all the modern OS adopt some memory protection systems.

Comment: Clean what? In theory you have to unallocate memory - restarting the machine would be a guaranteed way of doing it - in practice most OS's will free the memory upon program exit.

Comment: @user827992 I would be wary of using terms like "all the modern OS" since I could write one tomorrow that does not :-) (stupid idea but I could)

Comment: @AdrianCornish that a this is recent is not semantically equivalent to modern --- if you made a CRT monitor today it would be new, but not modern. Modern is a reflection features and style rather than actual creation date IMHO.

Comment: @tobyodavies Not true - I could have to write for a new platform that has 16K total RAM and does not have the space to deal with things like this. Example code for level 3 cache management on a new ultra low power CPU. You agree though that my point is valid even though obtuse :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish I would argue such a platform is antiquated, not modern.

Comment: Fair point :-) but bigger doesnt not mean modern. We are now just debating personal semantics and not helping the OP with is original question since we got diverted onto a more interesting subject

Comment: Hey guys, great discussion. It was not possible to go into school machine to restart. I tried disconnecting and connecting again. Does not work. So I ended up trying to remember just the old var name since there's only one pointer, and keep running the programs again, cleaning, and so on, and finally it worked..